# How to check if number is bit palindrome or not

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have to write a code to check if the number is bit palindrome. e.g. 9(1001) is bit palindrome but 6(110) is not a bit palindrome.

I have written the code to convert the number into a string which represents that numbers in binary and then checked for string palindrome. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can do this using bit wise operators. The idea is to read each bit, one at a time, of the number from right to left and generate another number using these bits from left to right. Finally, we compare these two numbers. 
If they are same, the original number is a binary bit palindrome.

```
int isBitPalindrome(int x) {
    int reversed = 0, aux = x;
    while (aux > 0) {
        /* 
        Before doing that shifting reversed to 
        right, to build it from left to right. 
        Takes LSB of aux and puts it as LSB of reversed
        variable.
        */
        reversed = (reversed  << 1) | (aux & 1);

        /*
        Loop depends on number of bits in aux. Takes next bit into 
        LSB position by shifting aux right once.
        */
        aux = aux >> 1;
    }
    return (reversed  == x) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: The approach sounds good, but the code has poor clarity. Why no meaningful variable-names? Good variable-names would be `x`, `reversed` and `remain`. And why the logical -> int for the return? Try to write code that's near readable English, use comments to explain more-complex bits (like building `y`).

Comment: @ThomasW Thanks for the suggestings. I have made those changes in my code.

Comment: Great! Good approach to the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Below implementation will execute in O(n/2), where n is bit length of given number:

```
#define LSB(bit_len) 0x1
#define MSB(bit_len) 0x1 << bit_len - 1

int isBitPalindrome(int x) {
    int i = 0, bit_len = sizeof(int) * 8;
    unsigned int left = 0, right = 0;

    while (i < bit_len / 2) {
        left = x << i & MSB(bit_len);
        right = x >> i & LSB(bit_len);

        if ((left == 0x0 && right == 0x0) ||
            (left == MSB(bit_len) && right == LSB(bit_len))
            i++;
        else
            break;
    }

    return (i == bit_len / 2) ? 1 : 0;
}
```